# Eclipse External Null Annotation for AbstractStreamEx.nonNull()

Tags: java, eclipse, streamex, external-annotations

Consider the following example code.  This code uses Eclipse's `@NonNull` and `@Nullable` annotations to check for `null`s.  Unfortunately, Eclipse flags an error on the line `map(toNonNull)`.

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable;
import one.util.streamex.StreamEx;

Function<@NonNull Integer, @Nullable Integer> toNull;
Function<@NonNull Integer, @NonNull Integer> toNonNull;

toNull    = value -> value;
toNonNull = value -> value;

StreamEx.
   of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).
   map(toNull).
   nonNull().
   map(toNonNull).   // Error is here
   count();
```

Here's the error message:

> Null type mismatch (type annotations): required
>   'Function'
>   but this expression has type
>   'Function<@NonNull Integer, @NonNull Integer>'

I would like to create an Eclipse External Annotation on [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/master/src/main/java/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.java)'s `nonNull()` (or more precisely [AbstractStreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/master/src/main/java/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.java#L634)'s `nonNull()`) so that Eclipse will know that the values in the stream can not be null.

Here's the start of the Eclipse External Annotation.

```
class one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx<TS>

nonNull
 ()TS;
 ()???;
```

What do I put for `???`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For StreamEx 0.6.4 or newer, StreamEx overrides `nonNull()` so that one can use the following External Annotation:

```
nonNull
 ()Lone/util/streamex/StreamEx<TT;>;
 ()L1one/util/streamex/StreamEx<T1T;>;
```

For StreamEx 0.6.3 or older, one ugly solution is to change the Java code.  This works around the compiler error.

```
StreamEx.
   of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).
   map(toNull).
   nonNull().
   map(item -> item != null ? toNonNull.apply(item) : null).
   count();
```